# Word for stating something as fact when narrator and audience knows it is untrue?

Tags: literature, literary-techniques, rhetorical-devices, literary-device, irony

I am looking for a literary term that is similar to irony. Basically, the narrator say something in an almost sarcastic way by stating something that everyone knows is untrue. The quote I am going off of is “...nothing mattered except that Lupin stop pretending that Sirius, who was standing feet from them behind that old curtain, was not going to emerge at any moment...”

Sirius of course has just died, and the narrator says that he is “standing feet from them behind that old curtain” when everyone knows that is simply not true. Is this some type of irony? Rhetorical statement? I need to know!

Comment: I don't think this is similar to irony, and it's not stated in a sarcastic way. It's simply reporting how a character feels about the situation; even if the narrator and the audience know it's not true, that doesn't mean the character knows or wants to admit the truth (which is the entire point here - Harry didn't want to admit that Sirius was actually dead).

Comment: Why can't both facts be true? Sirius has died, and he's standing feet from them behind the curtain but cannot cross back over?

Comment: Verbal irony _is_ when something everyone knows is untrue is stated in a matter-of fact way. "The world, as we all know, being flat ...." There's usually more than self-deprecating humour involved, admittedly. The general term for stating the opposite of what is meant to be understood is 'antiphrasis'.

Answer (score 0):

The closest would be "**political speech/doublespeak**"

Next would be "**propaganda**"

If used in the right context, the following words/phrases will mean that both narrator and audience knows that it is untrue.

- Lying through his/her teeth
- Prevarication
- Fabrication
- Speaking with forked tongue

Hope it is useful.